# AFNetworking HTTP POST upload image stopping when near completion

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, http-post, afnetworking

I am using the code below to HTTP POST a multi-part web form, including a JPEG image.

**Code:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:nameField.text forKey:@"name"];
[params setObject:emailField.text forKey:@"email"];
[params setObject:titleField.text forKey:@"title"];
[params setObject:dateString forKey:@"link"];
[params setObject:descriptionTV.text forKey:@"content"];
[params setObject:tag forKey:@"tags"];

NSData* sendData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadedPhoto.image, 1.0);
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                       path:@"form"
                                                                 parameters:params
                                                  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                                  {
                                      [formData appendPartWithFileData:sendData
                                                                  name:@"image"
                                                              fileName:@"image.jpeg"
                                                              mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                  }];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS! %@", operation.responseString);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"FAILED!!! %@", operation.responseString);
}];

[operation start];
```

**Web form:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" />
<input type="text" name="link" id="link" value="" />
<input type="text" name="content" id="content" value="" />
<input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" value="" />
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="" />
```

Every time I run the code, the image upload goes smooth until when the upload progress is about to be done (~99.5% completed). The operation's `completionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` blocks are never launched, and the app just freezes there.

Can anyone help me out with this? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

**Edit:**

I did a bit more investigation and found that it does the same even with an invalid request path, but I'm pretty sure I didn't type my form path wrongly. Also, when I replace the `constructingBodyWithBlock` block with `nil`, it will work properly.

**Edit 2:**

I did some snooping on AFNetworking's Github and found [a Github issue post](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/746) and [a similar post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415093/afnetworking-with-afjsonrequestoperation-and-filedata-never-completes). I tried the using `[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];` instead of `[operation start];` and making the `httpClient` a singleton, but the same problem still persists.

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution to this? Please help.

Comment: @ScarletWitch Sorry, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print the `NSError` in the failure callback? Maybe the server is expecting another mime type.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it simply returns the webpage's source code (similar to viewing a page source in a web browser).

Comment: Are you returning a valid JSON in your server-side code? It seems to me that this is not a AFNetworking problem, but a server-side one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have control over the web backend. I also had a hunch that it's a server-sided issue, so my partner is in the midst of changing the backend system to something better documented for the purpose.

Comment: @Jay, try to mimmic the AFNetworking call with ``cURL`` and check if you're receiving a valid JSON. If not, you have a server-side issue.