# Upload image to form in webview, without displaying image picker

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to fill up a web form and submit data without letting the user see the web form itself. I have tried using AFNetworking to do HTTP POST in the background, but I bumped into a [problem which I couldn't solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057283/afnetworking-http-post-upload-image-stopping-when-near-completion) and decided to try something else.

This time, I have a `UIWebView` which is hidden in the background. I then edit the text in the respective fields using Javascript in the `webViewDidFinishLoad:webView` as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:nameField.text     forKey:@"name"];
[params setObject:emailField.text    forKey:@"email"];
[params setObject:titleField.text    forKey:@"title"];
[params setObject:dateString         forKey:@"link"];
[params setObject:descriptionTV.text forKey:@"content"];
[params setObject:tag                forKey:@"tags"];

[params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, object);
    NSString *javascriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').value = '%@'",key,object];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
}];
```

Is there any way I could do the same, but for uploading images/files?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `NSHTTPRequest` to `POST` the image to the form directly.  There is no need to use a `UIWebView`, hidden or otherwise.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2330248/362730) for an example of how to implement this.  Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448378/362730) of this.